# Issue with subqueries in OrientDb

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to make a query that returns information between classes, (I am planning to convert them to edges later using the output from this query)

This is my test setup (I am using OrientDB 3.0.14):

```
CREATE CLASS users
INSERT INTO users CONTENT {"name": "user1", "state_code": "CA"}
INSERT INTO users CONTENT {"name": "user2", "state_code": "VA"}
INSERT INTO users CONTENT {"name": "other3", "state_code": "FL"}

CREATE CLASS states
INSERT INTO states CONTENT {"code": "CA", "name": "California"}
INSERT INTO states CONTENT {"code": "VA", "name": "Virginia"}
INSERT INTO states CONTENT {"code": "FL", "name": "Florida"}
```

Now,this query works fine, I can see the expected results:

```
SELECT name, state_code, $state FROM users LET $state=(SELECT FROM states WHERE code=$parent.$current.state_code)

+----+------+----------+---------------------------+
|#   |name  |state_code|$state                     |
+----+------+----------+---------------------------+
|0   |user1 |CA        |[{code:CA,name:California}]|
|1   |user2 |VA        |[{code:VA,name:Virginia}]  |
|2   |other3|FL        |[{code:FL,name:Florida}]   |
+----+------+----------+---------------------------+
```

So, I tried to add a subquery to filter and return only some of the records in users using:

```
SELECT name, state_code, $state FROM (SELECT FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'user%') LET $state=(SELECT FROM states WHERE code=$parent.$current.state_code)
+----+-----+----------+---------------------------+
|#   |name |state_code|$state                     |
+----+-----+----------+---------------------------+
|0   |user1|CA        |[{code:CA,name:California}]|
|1   |user2|VA        |[{code:CA,name:California}]|
+----+-----+----------+---------------------------+
```

I cannot find a way for the calculated value `$state` to return the proper values, it seems to be stuck in using only the first record ?

I really appreciate any help you can give me to figure out how to fix this query.